# AS3/Flash: check if a variable value exists in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible (in a short way) to check if:

```
var name = "Nora";
```

Exists in:

```
var names:Array = ["Mary", "Porter", "Nora", "Flint", "Elsa", "Clair",...];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`.indexOf()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29)

```
if( names.indexOf( name ) > -1 )
{
    // Success
}
```

Comment: So I can use if (names.indexOf( name )<0). Many thanks Cherniv, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Use array.indexOf(value).

```
if (names.indexOf(name) != -1)
{
    // Exist
}
else
{
    // Not exist
}
```